# How to calc IRR Internal rate of return given bond price

Tags: functions

How can i resolve this equation and find x ?! This is from the bond price formula, here we have the bond price of 101 and want to find the IRR(that i changed for x for simplicity).

$ 101 = \frac{5%}{x}+\frac{5%}{x^2}+\frac{5%}{x^3}+\frac{5%}{x^4}+\frac{5%}{x^5}+\frac{100%}{x^5}$

Thank you

Comment: You can do it numerically by hand, but it is a bunch of work.  Clearly $x$ is slightly greater than $1$.  You can use $1$ as a starting value, compute the derivative of the right hand side at $x=1$ and apply a step of Newton's method.  I would guess that will already be accurate enough, but if not do another step.

Comment: Thanks. So there`s no way to resolve this equation algebraically ?

Comment: Normally fifth degree equations cannot be solved by algebraic techniques unless you define some new functions.

Comment: In agreement with Ross, visually, if you let $u=1/x$ then you end up with a quintic polynomial $100u^5+5u^4+5u^3+5u^2+5u^2+5u-101=0$ which may have some kind of solution using Jacobi theta functions but you're in the realm of diminishing returns thereafter.

Comment: Hi: the bi-section method is often used to compute IRR since we generally know the interval where the solution lies. that might be quicker than newton's method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @asymptotic suggested, let $x=\frac 1u$ to face
$$100u^5+5u^4+5u^3+5u^2+5u^2+5u-101=0$$ Let $u=(1-\epsilon)$ and expand
$$0=24-560 \epsilon +1055 \epsilon ^2-1025 \epsilon ^3+505 \epsilon ^4-100
   \epsilon ^5$$ Consider now the this is an expansion up to $O\left(\epsilon ^6\right)$ and use [series reversion](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SeriesReversion.html). You will obtain
$$ \epsilon =z+\frac{211 }{112}z^2+\frac{33041}{6272} z^3+\frac{24013799
  }{1404928} z^4+\frac{674340297 }{11239424}z^5+O\left(z^6\right)$$ where $z=\frac{3}{70}$.

Using  all the terms (which is totally ridiculous)
$$\epsilon=\frac{884027232144411}{18890099916800000}\implies x=\frac{18890099916800000}{18006072684655589}=1.0491$$ while the "exact" solution is $1.0477$.

Notice that using $\epsilon=z=\frac{3}{70}$ already gives $x=\frac{70}{67}=1.0448$ which is the value of the very first iterate of Newton method (as suggested by @RossMillikan in comments).